# Validar tipos de datos traidos de un archivo de texto

Tags: c#, consola

Buen día.

Realizo una implementación en C#, en el cual deberá leer los datos un archivo de texto (esta parte ya la tengo) y cada uno de esos datos deberá ser de cierto tipo, es decir, en mi archivo de texto vienen precios, fechas, entre otros datos.

Tengo detalle al validar el dato del precio, ya que me indica el mensaje "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto", y continua con el proceso, y este no debería ser así, debería terminar la lectura de ese archivo y continuar con el siguiente.

```
#region Producto
    //Metodo con arreglo, asigna los datos de cada linea de producto
    public static Productos[] Producto(string startFolder)
    {
        string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        List<string> Datos = LeerArchvioTXT(startFolder);

        Productos[] lineas = new Productos[Datos.Count - 2];
        //FOR para leer los datos de los productos linea por linea
        for (int a = 2; a < Datos.Count; a++)
        {
            try
            {
                char separador = '|';
                string[] DatosCol;
                DatosCol = Datos[a].Split(separador);
                lineas[a - 2].Codigo = DatosCol[2];
                //lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Referencia
                lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Observaciones
                lineas[a - 2].Cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[7]); //Cantidad
                lineas[a - 2].Precio = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[8]); //Precio
                //lineas[a - 2].Impuesto1 = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[4]);//impuesto1
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return lineas;
    }
    #endregion
```

El mensaje me lo arroja en el catch, lo que no logro hacer es que termine el proceso si encuentra una excepción.

Anexo un ejemplo de un archivo de texto que manejo.

```
00|AAA010101AAA
01|1447AA|Paola Lizandra|AAA010101AAA|I|FA|9|04/13/2021|04|PUE|Pago en una sola exhibicion|P01|MXN||
02|1|MTZ01|Licencia Comercial Premium|16.00|43231500|Comentario en movimiento|2|AA||2
02|3|352|Carcinoembrionario Antígeno, Suero|16.00|85121800||1|494.7845||3
02|4|355|CA 125 Antígeno, Suero|16.00|85121800||1|515.5172||
```

Comment: Si pones un `break` dentro del `catch` va a salir del `for`.

Comment: Lo más probable es que la data esté mal estructurada, ergo, los índices se salen de lugar y se rompe la app

Comment: primero que nada debes de contar tus archivos en el folder y luego recorrer en funcion de la cantidad de archivos, si uno esta mal pues debe continuar con el otro archivo y asi sucesivamente pero no veo eso en tu codigo.

Comment: Hola @Manny, agradezco respuesta, esa parte ya la tengo implementada, si pasa archivo por archivo, pero lo que no logro es hacer que termine cuando encuentra una excepción.

Comment: @GeovaniLopez una idea seria  validar DatosCol que tenga datos antes de agregar a a las variables.

Comment: Hola @Manny, como podría realizar lo que comentas.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que pretendes es abortar la ejecución del método, deberías hacer un throw ex; dentro del catch y controlar la excepción desde afuera (desde donde invocas Producto(string startFolder)), y en ese punto, decides si harás algo con lo que se pudo recuperar o de plano ignorarás el poco o mucho contenido que haya adquirido ese método "Producto".

Al final, tu código quedaría algo así:

```
    public static void Foo()
    {
        Productos[] productos;
        foreach (string folder in Folders)
        {
            try
            {
                productos = Producto(folder);
                // Si no falló el método para obtener los productos, en seguida haces lo
                // que quieras con esos productos.
                ProcesaProductos(productos);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Aquí es en donde decidimos si haremos algo o no.
                // En tu caso, no vas a hacer nada con "productos".
            }
        }
    }

    #region Producto
    //Metodo con arreglo, asigna los datos de cada linea de producto
    public static Productos[] Producto(string startFolder)
    {
        string fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        List<string> Datos = LeerArchvioTXT(startFolder);

        Productos[] lineas = new Productos[Datos.Count - 2];
        //FOR para leer los datos de los productos linea por linea
        for (int a = 2; a < Datos.Count; a++)
        {
            try
            {
                char separador = '|';
                string[] DatosCol;
                DatosCol = Datos[a].Split(separador);
                lineas[a - 2].Codigo = DatosCol[2];
                //lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Referencia
                lineas[a - 2].Observaciones = DatosCol[6]; //Observaciones
                lineas[a - 2].Cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[7]); //Cantidad
                lineas[a - 2].Precio = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[8]); //Precio
                                                                      //lineas[a - 2].Impuesto1 = Convert.ToDouble(DatosCol[4]);//impuesto1
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return lineas;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Hola @Mario, agradezco respuesta, lo reviso y marco la respuesta como valida si esta funciona.

Comment: Hola @Mario, te comento que he agregado el throw ex, pero ahora me envía la excepción completa en pantalla y ahí se queda, no pasa al siguiente archivo, si no que sigue leyendo ese mismo archivo una y otra vez.

Comment: Es raro que se quede en el mismo archivo, pues al hacer "throw ex;" dentro del método "Producto", debería salirse de todo el método y debería ser cachada la excepción por el método externo, el cual debería iterar al siguiente archivo. ¿Es posible que pongas cómo dejaste el código?

Comment: Por cierto, para tu desarrollo personal, te recomiendo que adoptes el uso de convenciones de nombres (nomenclatura de nombres) en tu código, pues es confuso cuando los métodos llevan nombre de entidades, entre otras cosas.

Comment: Hola @Mario, modificare el código de la pregunta.